# Time of day math

Tags: html, math, time

I need to subtract time of day for races.

I have the the time of day from the finish and the TOD from the start:
   MM:SS.mss - MM:SS.mss =

I can't figure out how to get the answer.

Comment: Are we using Javascript here? PHP? There's got to be some sort of scripting going on to perform any sort of mathematical operation. Could you please post some code for clarification? (and congrats on your first post!)

Comment: Some one had an answer on here and I liked it.  I didn't copy it at the time thinking I could come back and copy when I needed it.  Now It's gone.  Something about    finish - start not sure but it was good

Comment: Yes, there was an answer on here that was deleted. The reason that the answerer deleted the answer was because the answer was written in C#, while OP asked for HTML5, and never specified another scripting language. I was just about to tell the answerer when it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to do math on dates and times is to convert the start date/time to an "epoch value", do the math as you normally would with any number (simply adding the number of milliseconds, for example a day would be 1000[ms]*60[s]*60[m]*24[h]), and then convert the new epoch value back to a date and time.

Most languages have a method for converting a human readable date into an epoch value and back.  Here are some examples:

http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/

Most languages also provide convenience methods for the algorithm I'm describing (epoch calculations) so you don't have to think real hard, but they all essentially work the same way under the covers -- convert your start date into the number of milliseconds since some distant point in time, add or subtract the time in milliseconds, then convert back to human readable form.

Comment: Ok so I'm new to this and what i'm trying to do is build something like a calculator.  I want to have 3 boxes across the top.  I want the cursor to move across the top and fill the boxes with the numbers entered on a key pad below.  I can build a keypad, but can't figure out how to build the boxes so the input moves across the fields.  So, box 1 would be mm  after typing the user inputs the two numbers on the number keys at the bottom, the cursor moves to ss then to mss then drops down to the next line to input the next series of mm:ss.mss

Comment: Is there a question in there?